# Unique session in a "live" Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

At work we use Shiny to develop management dashboards. The information source used to be flat files previously extracted from the database but now we are trying to develop a "live" dashboard allowing the user to query the database from within the dashboard. The dashboard is reached using a url and there is no login required to view the dashboard. Just point the browser and the dashboard loads.

I've got it working fine except for one problem. If two users are using the dashboard at the same time, running the same queries and creating the same tables, the results can become mixed. One user will see the results of another.

Queries are ran using an actionButton that runs a function such as:

```
dataTbl <- function(<select criteria>) {
  sqlQuery(connection, "select * from ... ")
}
```

How can each user have their own unique session so that regardless of the number of users at any one time, each is separate and independent of the others?

Comment: It might be that you are modifying global variables

Comment: Yes this is true. Functions are used to run sql scripts. eg: dataTbl <- sqlQuery(connection, "select * from.... ")

Answer (score 0):

You can do string search and replace, I would also suggest that you use `promises` package to do the querying https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html

```
dataTbl <- function(table,products) {
  qr <- "select * from TABLE where product = PRODUCTS"
  qr <- gsub("TABLE",table,qr)
  qr <- gsub("PRODUCTS",products,qr)
  sqlQuery(connection,qr)
}
```

Comment: Warning about SQL injections, users can enter SQL commands in products if they are read from an input. Use `glue` package for example

Comment: The example is what we use but the user only has a limited selection of options. The cannot manually enter their own criteria. The problem however is more in keeping the sessions separate for each user.

Comment: If they are not exposing the app to public and using it within org, it should be ok